# adding a value into the cache when the value isn’t in the cache

Tags: caching, appfabric

I want to program the basic CRUD operations of  caching (creating new  object , remove it , update...) i start by creating the object and  displaying its name this is my code:
(My cache name="default")

web.config:

```
..........

<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="dataCacheClient"
   type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientSection,
    Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core,
    Version=1.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
     </configSections>
     <dataCacheClient>
      <hosts>
        <host name="Amira-PC" cachePort="22233" />

        </hosts>
       </dataCacheClient>

         ......
```

Global.asax.cs :

```
     using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;

      namespace AppFabricCachingTest{
        public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
         {
         public static string CacheFactoryName = "CacheFactory";
          void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
        // Code qui s'exécute au démarrage de l'application


        var dcf = new DataCacheFactory();
        Application[CacheFactoryName] = dcf;
        DataCache myCache = dcf.GetCache("default");// cache name=mycache

        object myCachedItem = new Object();
        string myCachedItemKey = "MyCacheKey";
        myCache.Add(myCachedItemKey, myCachedItem);



     }
    .....

     `
```

Site.Master.cs

```
       `  
        using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;

         namespace AppFabricCachingTest
       {
           public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
               {
           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
              {

                }

    public string GetCachedName()
     {
       string name = null;
       string key ="MyCacheKey";

        var dcf = Application[Global.CacheFactoryName] as DataCacheFactory;

          if (dcf != null)
            {
    var cache = dcf.GetCache("default");
    name = cache.Get(key) as string;
    if (name == null)
    {
        name = "Windows Server App Fabric Cache ";
        cache.Put(key, name);

    }
    else
    {
        name += " From Cache!";

            }
             }
        else name = "dcf is NULL";
           return name;
       }

         }
     }
```

Site.Master :

```
 <body>
        <form runat="server">
             <div class="page">
                <div class="header">
                   <div class="title">
            <h1>
               <%= GetCachedName() %>
            </h1>
        </div>
            ...............
```

After running I got always "The dcf is NULL" and not the name of the object 
Any idea please,

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing declaration of other object as part of DataCacheFactory initialization.
The DataCacheFactory does not know, where it should gather cluster cache from.
Please try the below code

DataCacheServerEndpoint[] servers = new DataCacheServerEndpoint[1];
servers[0] = new DataCacheServerEndpoint("localhost", 22233);

// Setup the DataCacheFactory configuration.

DataCacheFactoryConfiguration factoryConfig = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
factoryConfig.Servers = servers;

// Create a configured DataCacheFactory object.

DataCacheFactory cacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory(factoryConfig);